# Recover data from drive with broken partition table

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, data-recovery

I have a laptop with Windows 7 installed in it. Recently it started showing corrupt windows installation, so I formatted the boot drive. But thereafter Windows installation itself showed that it could not create boot partition. So I am left without any OS and a f*ed up partition table. I tried recovering data using a Ubuntu 14.04 live usb. It shows error in mounting the drives. Is there any way to recover data as I cannot afford to lose it...
Here is the error in mounting:

```
**UNABLE TO ACCESS "ZERO"**
*Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/ubuntu/zero: Command-line 'mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/ubuntu/zero" exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MTF (record 0).
Failed to mount "dev/sda5": Input/output error. 
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory. Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.*
```

Comment: have you tried "chkdsk /r" with windows recovery console?

Comment: can't access anything... anyways, problem solved.. It was because the primary drive had been set as a dynamic drive and had to change the setting from BIOS